# Error al conectar bot hecho con Bot Framework al servicio de Custom Question Answering de Azure

Tags: c#, bot

He desarrollado un bot que se enlaza con el servicio de `LUIS` (lo cual lo hace perfecto), pero quería mejorar mi bot, para que en caso de no encontrar la intención en `LUIS` se fuera al nuevo servicio de `Azure Custom Questions and Answering` para revisar si la pregunta estaba en ese banco de preguntas, pero no logro conectarme a este último servicio ya que la conexión me da error.

Tengo el siguiente código para realizar dicha conexión:

```csharp
Uri endpoint = new Uri("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/language/:query-knowledgebases?projectName=xxxxxxxxx&api-version=2021-10-01&deploymentName=production");

AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
string projectName = "xxxxxxxxx";
string deploymentName = "production";
    
string question = "pregunta de ejemplo";
    
QuestionAnsweringClient client = new QuestionAnsweringClient(endpoint, credential);
QuestionAnsweringProject project = new QuestionAnsweringProject(projectName, deploymentName);
                
    
try {
  Response<AnswersResult> response = client.GetAnswers(question, project);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(ex.Message, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
}
```

El problema es cuando trato de obtener el response, cae en el catch y da erro de que no encuentra el servicio:

```bash
Resource not found

Status: 404 (Resource Not Found)

ErrorCode: 404

Content:

{“error”:{“code”:“404”,“message”: “Resource not found”}}
```

la url la saco del get prediction url del servicio question and answering

Comment: El problema es que no existe el recurso `/language/:query-knowledgebases` en la API `https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`. Podrías compartir la documentación en dónde encontraste esa URL?

Comment: @AndresGardiol gracias por la respuesta, me dió una idea de que en realidad la url endpoint de la API estaba mal. La sustituí por 

`https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/ `

y ya con eso sirve bien. Gracias